# Clone hard disk of old macbook to new macbook?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook mid 2014 with Yosemite on it. If I buy a new MacBook, can I clone the disk from the old MacBook to the new one and have it boot up just like if it was the old one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You will need a thunderbolt cable, boot the new computer in target disk mode, and use something like Carbon Copy Cloner to do the job.

Copying via the recovery partition is also possible, but fiddlier.

Comment: Sweet. I'll have to try this when the new MacBook arrives around the 20th. The old drive is 256gb while the new it 1tb, so u guess I'll also have to make the partition bigger.

Comment: CCC will clone disparate partition sizes with no issue. I'd check the new one can boot on the older OS first, before committing - otherwise use Migration Assistant instead.

Comment: The instructions I find run CCC in a live OS X to clone the disk of the live oS X to another drive. How can it copy bit-for-bit the live system if it's changing constantly?

Comment: Unix filesystems (including OS X) can be cloned while they are running. CCC knows not to include things like the virtual memory swap files and various caches. You don't need bit-for-bit as there are many gigabytes that are erased every boot. It works, I've done it many times.